# How do I restart a Mac using voiceover when filevault is enabled?

Tags: macos, filevault, login, voiceover

The Voiceover Login screen has a different UI/UX when FileVault is enabled. I am unable to navigate to different screen options using `VO` + `arrow` key. The [secret commands](https://twocanoes.com/12-customizations-for-the-mojave-macos-login-window-that-you-didnt-know-about/) like `>restart` do not work either when FileVault is enabled.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203986

#### Question

How do I select the “restart” or “shutdown” options at the bottom solely using Voiceover on a FileVault login screen?

[image: restart and shutdown options]

---

#### Reasons why I need to be able to do this

This feature is needed for me because I use an eGPU, and my monitors cannot display video from the Mac until after login due to FileVault restrictions. My Macbook is also docked in the closed position, and opening it would require me to disconnect it from the dock.